# Are the Heartseed entities some kind of plant?

Tags: kokoro-connect

The entity(ies) that keep causing the "random" phenomena with the Social Studies Club kids name themselves [Heartseed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiospermum). Sometimes translated as the linked plant genus. Even Wikipedia editors seem to have gone in the same train of thought. But that seems to be speculation.

But since the whole series is about connecting their hearts, it could be the case that they are really heart (as in a human's emotion-holding "organ" in popular culture) seeds.

Are they plant-ish, really?

Comment: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A6%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BA%E3%83%A9 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiospermum_halicacabum Googling the original term in Japanese "fuusen kazura" links to the articles above. Literally, it refers to the name of plants whose seed has a heart shape pattern. I guess since the seed has heart pattern outside, the name metaphorically refers to the fact that they cause people to expose their heart and their inner self?

Comment: @nhahtdh  Probably so, maybe I am trying to see if the writer or showmakers had voiced something about that. Maybe it is one of those inspirational sources some Japanese authors have when they fancy some name or category of names and then go all-out, like in Chaika, all the family names are car manufacturers. There may be something there, maybe not, but have to ask nonetheless.